# Content resolver database doesnt get auto updated

Tags: android, database, android-contentresolver

I  have an app the havily relies on the content resolver database

now if the user goes and manually moves or deletes his files, the content resolver database doesnt seem to immediately get updated of that

how do i make it get updated?

Answer (score 0):

It seems i can force a database update
by sending the following line before i query the database

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```